# unreachable statement on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, unreachable-statement

i got this unreachable statement at Andoid studio i try to fix for the data structure but nothing happend, can anyone help me?. The problem is on

`this.income += ((Income) this.li.get(i)).getJumlah();`

this is my code

```
public static int uang;
private Button btnDeveloper;
private Button btnExit;
private Button btnIncome;
private Button btnOutcome;
private Button btnPassword;
private Button btnReport;
private Dialog dialog;
private IncomeDataSource iDS;
private int income;
private Intent intent;
private ArrayList<Income> li = new ArrayList();
private ArrayList<Outcome> lo = new ArrayList();
private MoneyDataSource mDS;
private Money money;
private OutcomeDataSource oDS;
private int outcome;
private String tuang = "";
private TextView txtUang;


public void bindingList()
{
    this.li = getAllIncome();
    this.income = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (i >= this.li.size())
    {
        this.lo = getAllOutcome();
        this.outcome = 0;
    }
    for (int j = 0; ; j++)
    {
        if (j >= this.lo.size())
        {
            return;
            this.income += ((Income) this.li.get(i)).getJumlah();
            i++;
            break;
        }
        this.outcome += ((Outcome)this.lo.get(j)).getJumlah();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning just before `this.income += ((Income) this.li.get(i)).getJumlah();` thus making it unreachable.

Comment: `return;` causing issue

Comment: it is entering the 'if' and returning. problem with your for loop or if condition

Comment: Whats the point of that return? why dont you see it?

Comment: owh yeah i'm forgoting those :D cause i'm too sleepy, thanks its really helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the return from the if loop :)

```
public void bindingList()
{
    this.li = getAllIncome();
    this.income = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (i >= this.li.size())
    {
        this.lo = getAllOutcome();
        this.outcome = 0;
    }
    for (int j = 0; ; j++)
    {
        if (j >= this.lo.size())
        {

            this.income += ((Income) this.li.get(i)).getJumlah();
            i++;
            break;
        }
        this.outcome += ((Outcome)this.lo.get(j)).getJumlah();
    }
}
```

Comment: but i got this instead when i'm trying to runjava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0